# Histogram normalization

Tags: statistics, matlab, monte-carlo

I need to generate random numbers from Gaussian distribution and to draw an equalized histogram. I've generated them in Matlab using Box-Muller transformation. Since I wasn't  sure how to equalize the histogram, I was searching for a solution on internet and I found that the right way to equalize it is (in Matlab code):

```
Vnorm= V / (max(V) * sqrt(2*pi));
```

where V is row vector of random numbers genrated from Gaussian distribution.
Why is it devided by `max(V)*sqrt(2*pi)`? Is it the area covered by histogram (non-normalized)?

The complete code is the one on this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ll6cbASqdbbobQRU19tu9GzDhG2_nhhJJFsbRduEixk/edit?usp=sharing) (I don't know how to write it properly here so I put in on google drive).

Comment: I believe it's called *histogram equalization*.

Comment: @barakmanos Thank you! I will correct it. Can you help me about my question?

Comment: In order to tell you the equalization formula, I need you to tell me the range of the values.

Comment: It's $(-\infty, \infty)$ .

Comment: @barakmanos I would be thankful if you would write me the rule how to find that formula in general case. I will have to do the same for another function ( $\frac{x+e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2*\pi}*erf(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})}$ on [-1,1] interval so I would like to know learn how to do it. Thank you a lot!

Comment: 1. Generate the random values. 2. Sort them in ascending order. 3. Remember the `Min` and `Max` values. 4. Build a look-up table that maps each value to the number of values smaller than itself (this is essentially a discrete integral of the original values). 5. Convert the look-up table from its range (which goes between $0$ and the total number of values), to the range `[Min,Max]`.

Comment: @barakmanos I think in my answer I figured out that this computation actually does a (weird form of) histogram normalization.

Comment: Maybe this for homework, but I assume that you're aware that you can use `randn` ([documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html)) to compute normal variates directly (and much or quickly) in Matlab? This uses the very fast Ziggurat method by default, but by working with the `Randstream` class ([documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randstream.html)) directly, you can use the [polar form](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randstream.html#brtliy_) of Box-Muller.

Comment: In new enough versions of Matlab, you might also try the `histogram` function ([documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html)) with the [`'Normalization'`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html#inputarg_Normalization) option. Something like `histogram([val1,val2],m,'Normalization','pdf');` in your case maybe.

Comment: @horchler I am allowed to use only random numbers generator so I have to do it this way or some other way if I find it. This way of generation seems pretty simple and I understand it.
As about histogram function with Normalization option, I tried to use it but I always get an error message **"Undefined function 'histogram' for input arguments of type 'double'"** and I don't know how to solve it. It also happens when I copy example from MathWorks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Box–Muller transform is a numerical method to generate standard-normally distributed random numbers, i.e. realizations of $N(0,1)$.

The density of the standard normal distribution is
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ -\frac{x^2}{2} }.
$$
This density reaches its maximal value of $1 / \sqrt{2 \pi}$ at $x = 0$.

So it appears that whoever gave you that rule intends to scale the histogram from its empirical maximal value `max(V)` to the maximal density `1 / sqrt(2*pi)`.

---

The difference between the density and the histogram is that the former is a continuous function whose integral over the whole range of values is 1 (it is normalized), while the latter is a sequence of counts. The above procedure tries to turn the histogram into a density estimate by adjusting it based on the empirical maximum. That procedure assumes that the correct distribution is known, and even if that's true it is not necessarily optimal (a maximum is sensitive to outliers).

A better procedure is to turn the histogram into a density estimate in a distribution-independent way, by numerically replicating the normalization process:

```
Vnorm = V / (sum(V) * dV)
```

where `dV` is the histogram bin width. Here `sum(V) * dV` is the discrete analogon of the integral, and the histogram is normalized by scaling it such that the "integral" becomes 1.

Comment: I made a correction. It seems ok. Would you check out if it's what you meant (I made a correction in the code I attached in question)?
Should I use this formula that you wrote in all problems of this type?

Comment: @user217351, yes, the code looks good and the result, too. Just one thing: I originally used `trapz` in my answer, which is ok, but I think using `sum` is even better. See my edited answer. And yes, this is a general solution that should work with random variables with all kinds of densities. An alternative that you might consider is not to use the histogram, but to use a "kernel density estimate", see `ksdensity` (in the Statistics Toolbox).

Comment: Thank you! I will try to do it using ksdensity. :)